# How can I end an appointment series in Outlook which was started with No end date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010, time

I moved. I am using Outlook and track my time by using a series which has the location fix. I want to change the location starting from today. This is what I tried:

1. Open the series.
2. Recurrence.
3. End by: Mo 13.06.2012.
4. Press OK.

Then I get the message;

> Any exceptions associated with this recurring appointment will be
>   cancelled. Is this OK?

Of course it is not OK since I modified a lot of appointments for which I used the series only as starting point to have the Location fix.

Can I set an end date without modifying the old entries? Or can I at least delete every appointment from now on in order to create a new series?

Comment: Confirmed to still exist as a problem in Outlook 2010.

Comment: Confirmed to still exist as a problem in Office 365 Outlook Version 2002.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found, it would appear you are not the only one to run into this. You will change all appointments in the series if you choose *"OK"* on that message.

**The solution** is to export the calendar to Excel or CSV and then import the appointment history in question as individual appointments. Once you've done that, you can delete the original meeting and recreate it with the settings you need.

Here is the [TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/b2d65fca-5848-4a4b-9e6a-c769d9fb0189) where I found the solution.

Comment: This approach is not ideal for appointments with multiple attendees and also any which have lengthy notes and/or attachments. Some more of the pitfalls are mentioned in the comments here: http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2008/12/change-outlook-recurring-appointments-without-losing-exceptions/